# How would infinitism intersect ethical beliefs?

Tags: ethics, reference-request, knowledge, infinite

Assuming that some moral knowledge is to be action-guiding, how could one appeal to an infinite chain of reasons to justify moral beliefs? (This is at least another "proof-of-concept" issue re: infinitism.)

I was thinking this: start from a process of practical deontic inquiry akin to a [methodology of the categories of freedom](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280102422_Kant%27s_Categories_of_Freedom), but have infinitely many categories, one for each operator implied by an infinite-dimensional deontic [Moretti structure](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11787-009-0003-4), and so say that an ethical belief like, "X is permitted," is infinitistically justified to the extent that one has reasons for, "Y is obligated," "Z is supererogated," etc. I.e. one cannot free-floatingly justify individual deontic claims but must situate them with respect to as many deontic operators/categories as possible, out of an infinity of available operators/categories.

This is just a programmatic image, for now, but is it going in the direction of ethical infinitism? Or would the reasons not be chained together in the right way to represent an infinite regress appropriately?

PS: [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24441787?seq=1) is obviously relevant but I don't have a subscription that allows me to read the full article